# FixedColumn in StringGrid

Tags: tstringgrid, c++builder-xe2

It is possible to fix for example only third row in StringGrid?. StringGrid have property FixedColumn but you can start fixing columns only from the begining.

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

TStringGrid does not natively support that, no. But you can owner-draw the cells to make them look like fixed cells, at least.